# How to mix multiple PCM audio packages (Voice streaming)

Tags: java, android, audio

I am developing a java voice chat for a game, I have a problem with the audio mix when several players are talking at the same time. The audio is only sent to nearby players, so I'm storing each user's buffers separately on the client and sending the id along with the voice packet on the server. To listen, I'm going through the list of users and checking the buffers of existing users to reproduce them. However, I have a problem with audio mixing, probably mixing it wrong. How should I mix these audio packages? Audio is 16-bit PCM. When several players are talking together, there is a lot of noise/hiss in these audios, the audio is practically inaudible.

What would be the correct algorithm to apply to this mixer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my limited experience with mike inputs, my starting point would be to try the following steps:

1. convert 16-bit bytes to PCM
2. (consider applying a low-pass filter to the PCM, and possibly volume gain)
3. add the PCM values together from each line being mixed
4. convert PCM back to bytes

I can't tell from your description if you are doing step 1 correctly.

A possible place for further research might be at jitsi.org. Their service is written in Java and is open source. It would be interesting to know how they handle this. But it seems to me the most usual thing is that only one line is selected and played at any one time. There may be good reasons for this limitation. But I don't know if it's technical (e.g.,the noise accumulates in a way that drowns out the voices) or if it's just that people talking at the same time create mass confusion quite easily. I supposed there may be echoes/feedback considerations as well. I will be looking forward to seeing what information other people might contribute on this.